# Terraform rollback to some input state

Tags: terraform

I have a terraform state file with me. Can I use that to provision the infra instead of providing terraform config files(.tf)?

I basically need the functionality to support rollbacks. So, in case some failure happens while running some terraform command, I want to rollback to the previous state.

Comment: Hello @Vaibhav - Please provide some more information as the information you have given is not sufficient.

Comment: Let's say I do a terraform apply, create a resource R1 and get a terraform state S1. Then again I do terraform apply, this time I create another resource R2 and state file updates to S2. Now can I rollback to previous S1 state?

Comment: The state file is a record of what terraform thinks is currently there.  To rollback to a previous version, you should instead re-apply the scripts that got you there.  They'll use the current state to work out what needs to change to go back.  IE keep your scripts versioned, not your state.

Comment: @JamesThorpe What if I am using targets argument with apply command. Now for rolling back to some state, I will need to know what targets went in. I may have had multiple targets in a single command or ran "apply" multiple times with different targets. Now in this case, I will not only need to track the scripts, but the commands as well. Any other simpler way to do this?

Comment: Yes, don't do that.  [The docs](https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/plan.html#resource-targeting) say _"This targeting capability is provided for exceptional circumstances, such as recovering from mistakes or working around Terraform limitations. It is not recommended to use -target for routine operations, since this can lead to undetected configuration drift and confusion about how the true state of resources relates to configuration."_  It goes on to recommend breaking up your config into smaller scripts.

Answer (score 1):

Rollbacks are not well-supported. You can do this in Terraform Enterprise or Terraform Cloud, but it is not trivial. Here is a [link to the HashiCorp Support article](https://support.hashicorp.com/hc/en-us/articles/360001151948-Modifying-Terraform-states-in-Terraform-Enterprise-or-Terraform-Cloud) that explains the process.

Basically, you will find the last known good state file, download it to your local system, change the backend, then move the state file. If you're really lucky, you can pull the state and then push the desired state. Be careful around the version of the CLI terraform and the version in Enterprise or Cloud.

Answer (score 0):

please have a look on following 2 links
https://developers.cloudflare.com/terraform/tutorial/roll-back/
[How to Rollback to Previous State in terraform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57821319/how-to-rollback-to-previous-state-in-terraform?r=SearchResults&s=2|78.0062)

Both recommend to version control your .tf files.
Unfortunately no .tfstate mentioned.
So it seems the only way to go is wih .tf files and not with the .tfstate.