# How to Rollback to Previous State in terraform

Tags: terraform

I am working on terraform tasks and trying to understand how state files work. I have created main.tf file which has

```
vpc,firewall,subnet,compute_instance
```

which has to be create in GCP. So i have applied this to GCP environment and a file name `terraform.tfstate` file got created and i did backup of this file into folder called 1st-run.

Now i have updated my `main.tf` with

```
2vpc,2firewalls,2subnets,compute_instance
```

as i need to add another nic for my vm.Did terraform apply and environment got created and terraform.tfstate file got created. I did backup of this file into folder called `2nd-run`.

I want to rollback the environment where i have executed for 1st-run. I have that state file which is in 1st-run folder.

What is the command to rollback by using statefile instead of touching the code so that automatically my GCP environment will have

```
vpc,firewall,subnet,compute_instance
```

which i have executed for the 1st time.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There is no way to roll back to a previous state as described in a state file in Terraform today. Terraform always plans changes with the goal of moving from the prior state (the latest state snapshot) to the goal state represented by the configuration. Terraform also uses the configuration for information that is not tracked in the state, such as the provider configurations.

The usual way to represent "rolling back" in Terraform is to put your configuration in version control and commit before each change, and then you can use your version control system's features to revert to an older configuration if needed.

Not all changes can be rolled back purely by reverting a VCS change though. For example, if you added a new `provider` block and resources for that provider all in one commit and then applied the result, in order to roll back you'd need to change the configuration to still include the `provider` block but *not* include any of the `resource` blocks, so you'd need to adjust the configuration during the revert. Terraform will then use the remaining `provider` block to configure the provider to run the destroy actions, after which you can finally remove the `provider` block too.

Comment: any suggestion on how to not include any resource blocks while reverting back to the previous VCS commit within a CI environment?

Answer (score 11):

While there are commands to [manipulate state](https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/state/mv.html), there is no command to rollback to the previous state, i.e. before the last `terraform apply`.

However, if you use a [remote S3 backend](https://www.terraform.io/docs/backends/types/s3.html) with a [dynamodb lock table](https://blog.gruntwork.io/how-to-manage-terraform-state-28f5697e68fa#7077), it is possible to roll back if versioning was enabled on the S3 bucket. For example, you could copy the previous version such that it becomes the latest version. You then must also update the digest in the dynamodb table, otherwise the `terraform init` will give you a message like:

```
Error refreshing state: state data in S3 does not have the expected content.

This may be caused by unusually long delays in S3 processing a previous state
update.  Please wait for a minute or two and try again. If this problem
persists, and neither S3 nor DynamoDB are experiencing an outage, you may need
to manually verify the remote state and update the Digest value stored in the
DynamoDB table to the following value: vvvvvvvvvvvvvv
```

You can just use this value to update the table and the rollback is done. To revert it, simply delete the last state from the S3 bucket so it goes back to its old "latest" and update the dynamodb table back to the corresponding digest.

Note that remote state is shared with your co-workers, so the above procedure should be avoided.

It's important to understand that changing the state files won't change the infrastructure by itself. That should be done by versioning the terraform code and doing `terraform plan` and `terraform apply` on the code that describes the desired infrastructure.

Answer (score 0):

1. make sure versioning is enable for AWS bucket which maintaining your tfstate files in AWS.
2. by enabling (show version / view) versioning inside bucket i found tfstate file by name.
3. Deleted the latest version which causes mismatch (as in my case it is for terraform version), it add delete marker file for that version. means it actually backup after deletion. you can easily restore original file back by just deleting this added delete marker file.)
4. then i looked into old versions of tfstate files to restore back, by checking history of deployment, downloaded required one (after download ca see details, for me its checking terraform correct version match)
5. then uploaded that old tfstate file to the same location from where i deleted conflicted tfstate file.
6. on resume deployment was getting error like below.

   Error refreshing state: state data in S3 does not have the expected content.

   This may be caused by unusually long delays in S3 processing a previous state
   update.  Please wait for a minute or two and try again. If this problem
   persists, and neither S3 nor DynamoDB are experiencing an outage, you may need
   to manually verify the remote state and update the Digest value stored in the
   DynamoDB table to the following value: b55*****************************

which means there is digest value already present for previous tfstate lock file which need update with this new value, found in DynamoDB>table>view table details.

7. on resume deployment in spinnaker able to complete deployment ( exceptional case : but in my case the latest pipeline was included changes in which there was destroying unused resource, which was created using different provider, hence I required to first revert back the provider first then on resume I able to successfully deploy the changes.)